# Extract JSON values and print to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a JSON object and my goal is to extract the values and list them out in HTML. I'm trying to use jQuery's `.each` function. The JSON object is listed below.

```
 var routeSchedule = {

      "northBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station" : "stop 1",
          "times": ["7:16 AM","7:36 AM","7:56 AM","8:16 AM","8:36 AM","8:56 AM","9:16 AM","9:36 AM","9:56 AM","10:16 AM","10:36 AM","10:56 AM","11:16 AM","11:36 AM","11:56 AM","12:16 PM","12:36 PM","12:56 PM","1:16 PM","1:36 PM","1:56 PM","2:16 PM","2:36 PM","2:56 PM","3:16 PM","3:36 PM","3:56 PM","4:16 PM","4:36 PM","4:56 PM","5:16 PM","5:36 PM","5:56 PM","6:16 PM","6:36 PM","6:56 PM","7:16 PM","7:36 PM","7:56 PM","8:16 PM","8:36 PM","8:56 PM","9:16 PM","9:36 PM","9:56 PM","10:16 PM","10:36 PM","10:56 PM","11:16 PM","11:36 PM","11:56 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 2",
          "times": ["7:02 AM","7:22 AM","7:42 AM","8:02 AM","8:22 AM","8:42 AM","9:02 AM","9:22 AM","9:42 AM","10:02 AM","10:22 AM","10:42 AM","11:02 AM","11:22 AM","11:42 AM","12:02 PM","12:22 PM","12:42 PM","1:02 PM","1:22 PM","1:42 PM","2:02 PM","2:22 PM","2:42 PM","3:02 PM","3:22 PM","3:42 PM","4:02 PM","4:22 PM","4:42 PM","5:02 PM","5:22 PM","5:42 PM","6:02 PM","6:22 PM","6:42 PM","7:02 PM","7:22 PM","7:42 PM","8:02 PM","8:22 PM","8:42 PM","9:02 PM","9:22 PM","9:42 PM","10:02 PM","10:22 PM","10:42 PM","11:02 PM","11:22 PM","11:42 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 3",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }

      ],

      "southBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station": "stop 4",
          "times": ["6:59 AM","7:19 AM","7:39 AM","7:59 AM","8:19 AM","8:39 AM","8:59 AM","9:19 AM","9:39 AM","9:59 AM","10:19 AM","10:39 AM","10:59 AM","11:19 AM","11:39 AM","11:59 AM","12:19 PM","12:39 PM","12:59 PM","1:19 PM","1:39 PM","1:59 PM","2:19 PM","2:39 PM","2:59 PM","3:19 PM","3:39 PM","3:59 PM","4:19 PM","4:39 PM","4:59 PM","5:19 PM","5:39 PM","5:59 PM","6:19 PM","6:39 PM","6:59 PM","7:19 PM","7:39 PM","7:59 PM","8:19 PM","8:39 PM","8:59 PM","9:19 PM","9:39 PM","9:59 PM","10:19 PM","10:39 PM","10:59 PM","11:19 PM","11:39 PM"]
          },
          {
          "station": "stop 5",
          "times": ["7:01 AM","7:21 AM","7:41 AM","8:01 AM","8:21 AM","8:41 AM","9:01 AM","9:21 AM","9:41 AM","10:01 AM","10:21 AM","10:41 AM","11:01 AM","11:21 AM","11:41 AM","12:01 PM","12:21 PM","12:41 PM","1:01 PM","1:21 PM","1:41 PM","2:01 PM","2:21 PM","2:41 PM","3:01 PM","3:21 PM","3:41 PM","4:01 PM","4:21 PM","4:41 PM","5:01 PM","5:21 PM","5:41 PM","6:01 PM","6:21 PM","6:41 PM","7:01 PM","7:21 PM","7:41 PM","8:01 PM","8:21 PM","8:41 PM","9:01 PM","9:21 PM","9:41 PM","10:01 PM","10:21 PM","10:41 PM","11:01 PM","11:21 PM","11:41 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 6",
          "times": ["7:03 AM","7:23 AM","7:43 AM","8:03 AM","8:23 AM","8:43 AM","9:03 AM","9:23 AM","9:43 AM","10:03 AM","10:23 AM","10:43 AM","11:03 AM","11:23 AM","11:43 AM","12:03 PM","12:23 PM","12:43 PM","1:03 PM","1:23 PM","1:43 PM","2:03 PM","2:23 PM","2:43 PM","3:03 PM","3:23 PM","3:43 PM","4:03 PM","4:23 PM","4:43 PM","5:03 PM","5:23 PM","5:43 PM","6:03 PM","6:23 PM","6:43 PM","7:03 PM","7:23 PM","7:43 PM","8:03 PM","8:23 PM","8:43 PM","9:03 PM","9:23 PM","9:43 PM","10:03 PM","10:23 PM","10:43 PM","11:03 PM","11:23 PM","11:43 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 7",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }
      ]
    }
```

The HTML block is listed below, this is just a reference, I need to list out all the times in a list item, but my only problem is getting data out of the JSON object.

```
<div>
  <h1>Route Schedules</h1>

  <div class="northbound">
    <h2>{Stop 1}</h2>
    <h3>Times</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="southbound">
    <h2>{Stop 2}</h2>
    <h3>Times</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
      <li>5:18</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Where I'm stuck:

```
 $.each(routeSchedule.southBoundWeekday, function(key, value) {

        $.each(value[times], function(time) {
            console.log(time)
        });

  });
```

Comment: There is not JSON in your question. Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: `value.times`, not `value[times]`.

Comment: @str It's quite common to represent a piece of JSON in object literal notation for the sake of asking a question.  It's easier than wrapping it in an async function that returns real JSON, less error-prone and easier to read.

Comment: And once it's represented as an object, it's not JSON anymore, so there's no reason to refer to it as JSON.

Comment: @JonathanRys There is no need for an async function. It is as easy as `const json = '{"foo": "bar"}'; const notJson = {"foo": "bar"};`. Asking a question about JSON with code not including any JSON is misleading and often requires comments for clarification.

Comment: @DanielBeck what is the effective difference between ```const notJSONAnymore = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');``` and ```const notJson = {"foo": "bar"};``` other than readability?  Can't we just assume that an object literal is parsed JSON on SO?

Comment: The effective difference, @JonathanRys, is that your first example includes JSON, and your second example does not include any JSON.   There's no reason to use the wrong name for things just because one can be converted into the other.  There's also no reason for you to help perpetuate peoples' confusion between a transport protocol and a native language feature. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm not trying to perpetuate confusion, in fact, I'm trying to do the opposite.  I just don't agree that we need to be so picky about this particular differentiation in this particular context. If the OP had posted JSON as you suggest, they wouldn't have a working code example without using `JSON.parse` furthermore it's quite normal to test functions that one intends to have receive JSON in with an object literal during development. If this was a blog post I would agree with you fully, but using proper terminology wouldn't improve this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$.each(routeSchedule.southBoundSaturday, function (indx, rowElement) {
  var container = $("<div class=\"southBoundSaturday\"></div>");
  var title = $("<h2></h2>");
  title.html(rowElement.station);

  var subtitle = $("<h3>Times</h3>");
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");

  $.each(rowElement.times, function (i, rowTimes) {
    var li = $("<li></li>");
    li.html(rowTimes);

    $ul.append(li);
  });

  container.append(title);
  container.append(subtitle);
  container.append($ul);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `southBoundWeekday` key in your JSON and you need to use quotes around your key `value["times"]` otherwise the interpreter thinks that's a variable.  Also, you were trying to print the index inside the second `.each`.  Try this instead:

```js
var routeSchedule = {

      "northBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station" : "stop 1",
          "times": ["7:16 AM","7:36 AM","7:56 AM","8:16 AM","8:36 AM","8:56 AM","9:16 AM","9:36 AM","9:56 AM","10:16 AM","10:36 AM","10:56 AM","11:16 AM","11:36 AM","11:56 AM","12:16 PM","12:36 PM","12:56 PM","1:16 PM","1:36 PM","1:56 PM","2:16 PM","2:36 PM","2:56 PM","3:16 PM","3:36 PM","3:56 PM","4:16 PM","4:36 PM","4:56 PM","5:16 PM","5:36 PM","5:56 PM","6:16 PM","6:36 PM","6:56 PM","7:16 PM","7:36 PM","7:56 PM","8:16 PM","8:36 PM","8:56 PM","9:16 PM","9:36 PM","9:56 PM","10:16 PM","10:36 PM","10:56 PM","11:16 PM","11:36 PM","11:56 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 2",
          "times": ["7:02 AM","7:22 AM","7:42 AM","8:02 AM","8:22 AM","8:42 AM","9:02 AM","9:22 AM","9:42 AM","10:02 AM","10:22 AM","10:42 AM","11:02 AM","11:22 AM","11:42 AM","12:02 PM","12:22 PM","12:42 PM","1:02 PM","1:22 PM","1:42 PM","2:02 PM","2:22 PM","2:42 PM","3:02 PM","3:22 PM","3:42 PM","4:02 PM","4:22 PM","4:42 PM","5:02 PM","5:22 PM","5:42 PM","6:02 PM","6:22 PM","6:42 PM","7:02 PM","7:22 PM","7:42 PM","8:02 PM","8:22 PM","8:42 PM","9:02 PM","9:22 PM","9:42 PM","10:02 PM","10:22 PM","10:42 PM","11:02 PM","11:22 PM","11:42 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 3",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }

      ],

      "southBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station": "stop 4",
          "times": ["6:59 AM","7:19 AM","7:39 AM","7:59 AM","8:19 AM","8:39 AM","8:59 AM","9:19 AM","9:39 AM","9:59 AM","10:19 AM","10:39 AM","10:59 AM","11:19 AM","11:39 AM","11:59 AM","12:19 PM","12:39 PM","12:59 PM","1:19 PM","1:39 PM","1:59 PM","2:19 PM","2:39 PM","2:59 PM","3:19 PM","3:39 PM","3:59 PM","4:19 PM","4:39 PM","4:59 PM","5:19 PM","5:39 PM","5:59 PM","6:19 PM","6:39 PM","6:59 PM","7:19 PM","7:39 PM","7:59 PM","8:19 PM","8:39 PM","8:59 PM","9:19 PM","9:39 PM","9:59 PM","10:19 PM","10:39 PM","10:59 PM","11:19 PM","11:39 PM"]
          },
          {
          "station": "stop 5",
          "times": ["7:01 AM","7:21 AM","7:41 AM","8:01 AM","8:21 AM","8:41 AM","9:01 AM","9:21 AM","9:41 AM","10:01 AM","10:21 AM","10:41 AM","11:01 AM","11:21 AM","11:41 AM","12:01 PM","12:21 PM","12:41 PM","1:01 PM","1:21 PM","1:41 PM","2:01 PM","2:21 PM","2:41 PM","3:01 PM","3:21 PM","3:41 PM","4:01 PM","4:21 PM","4:41 PM","5:01 PM","5:21 PM","5:41 PM","6:01 PM","6:21 PM","6:41 PM","7:01 PM","7:21 PM","7:41 PM","8:01 PM","8:21 PM","8:41 PM","9:01 PM","9:21 PM","9:41 PM","10:01 PM","10:21 PM","10:41 PM","11:01 PM","11:21 PM","11:41 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 6",
          "times": ["7:03 AM","7:23 AM","7:43 AM","8:03 AM","8:23 AM","8:43 AM","9:03 AM","9:23 AM","9:43 AM","10:03 AM","10:23 AM","10:43 AM","11:03 AM","11:23 AM","11:43 AM","12:03 PM","12:23 PM","12:43 PM","1:03 PM","1:23 PM","1:43 PM","2:03 PM","2:23 PM","2:43 PM","3:03 PM","3:23 PM","3:43 PM","4:03 PM","4:23 PM","4:43 PM","5:03 PM","5:23 PM","5:43 PM","6:03 PM","6:23 PM","6:43 PM","7:03 PM","7:23 PM","7:43 PM","8:03 PM","8:23 PM","8:43 PM","9:03 PM","9:23 PM","9:43 PM","10:03 PM","10:23 PM","10:43 PM","11:03 PM","11:23 PM","11:43 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 7",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }
      ]
    }


$.each(routeSchedule.southBoundSaturday, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value["times"], function(index, time) {
    console.log(time)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To add that data to the HTML is a bit more complicated.  It's good practice to create a document fragment and then add all your pieces to it before appending to the DOM.  You could also use templates like handlebars or mustache, but here's the JS way.:

```js
var routeSchedule = {

      "northBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station" : "stop 1",
          "times": ["7:16 AM","7:36 AM","7:56 AM","8:16 AM","8:36 AM","8:56 AM","9:16 AM","9:36 AM","9:56 AM","10:16 AM","10:36 AM","10:56 AM","11:16 AM","11:36 AM","11:56 AM","12:16 PM","12:36 PM","12:56 PM","1:16 PM","1:36 PM","1:56 PM","2:16 PM","2:36 PM","2:56 PM","3:16 PM","3:36 PM","3:56 PM","4:16 PM","4:36 PM","4:56 PM","5:16 PM","5:36 PM","5:56 PM","6:16 PM","6:36 PM","6:56 PM","7:16 PM","7:36 PM","7:56 PM","8:16 PM","8:36 PM","8:56 PM","9:16 PM","9:36 PM","9:56 PM","10:16 PM","10:36 PM","10:56 PM","11:16 PM","11:36 PM","11:56 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 2",
          "times": ["7:02 AM","7:22 AM","7:42 AM","8:02 AM","8:22 AM","8:42 AM","9:02 AM","9:22 AM","9:42 AM","10:02 AM","10:22 AM","10:42 AM","11:02 AM","11:22 AM","11:42 AM","12:02 PM","12:22 PM","12:42 PM","1:02 PM","1:22 PM","1:42 PM","2:02 PM","2:22 PM","2:42 PM","3:02 PM","3:22 PM","3:42 PM","4:02 PM","4:22 PM","4:42 PM","5:02 PM","5:22 PM","5:42 PM","6:02 PM","6:22 PM","6:42 PM","7:02 PM","7:22 PM","7:42 PM","8:02 PM","8:22 PM","8:42 PM","9:02 PM","9:22 PM","9:42 PM","10:02 PM","10:22 PM","10:42 PM","11:02 PM","11:22 PM","11:42 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 3",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }

      ],

      "southBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station": "stop 4",
          "times": ["6:59 AM","7:19 AM","7:39 AM","7:59 AM","8:19 AM","8:39 AM","8:59 AM","9:19 AM","9:39 AM","9:59 AM","10:19 AM","10:39 AM","10:59 AM","11:19 AM","11:39 AM","11:59 AM","12:19 PM","12:39 PM","12:59 PM","1:19 PM","1:39 PM","1:59 PM","2:19 PM","2:39 PM","2:59 PM","3:19 PM","3:39 PM","3:59 PM","4:19 PM","4:39 PM","4:59 PM","5:19 PM","5:39 PM","5:59 PM","6:19 PM","6:39 PM","6:59 PM","7:19 PM","7:39 PM","7:59 PM","8:19 PM","8:39 PM","8:59 PM","9:19 PM","9:39 PM","9:59 PM","10:19 PM","10:39 PM","10:59 PM","11:19 PM","11:39 PM"]
          },
          {
          "station": "stop 5",
          "times": ["7:01 AM","7:21 AM","7:41 AM","8:01 AM","8:21 AM","8:41 AM","9:01 AM","9:21 AM","9:41 AM","10:01 AM","10:21 AM","10:41 AM","11:01 AM","11:21 AM","11:41 AM","12:01 PM","12:21 PM","12:41 PM","1:01 PM","1:21 PM","1:41 PM","2:01 PM","2:21 PM","2:41 PM","3:01 PM","3:21 PM","3:41 PM","4:01 PM","4:21 PM","4:41 PM","5:01 PM","5:21 PM","5:41 PM","6:01 PM","6:21 PM","6:41 PM","7:01 PM","7:21 PM","7:41 PM","8:01 PM","8:21 PM","8:41 PM","9:01 PM","9:21 PM","9:41 PM","10:01 PM","10:21 PM","10:41 PM","11:01 PM","11:21 PM","11:41 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 6",
          "times": ["7:03 AM","7:23 AM","7:43 AM","8:03 AM","8:23 AM","8:43 AM","9:03 AM","9:23 AM","9:43 AM","10:03 AM","10:23 AM","10:43 AM","11:03 AM","11:23 AM","11:43 AM","12:03 PM","12:23 PM","12:43 PM","1:03 PM","1:23 PM","1:43 PM","2:03 PM","2:23 PM","2:43 PM","3:03 PM","3:23 PM","3:43 PM","4:03 PM","4:23 PM","4:43 PM","5:03 PM","5:23 PM","5:43 PM","6:03 PM","6:23 PM","6:43 PM","7:03 PM","7:23 PM","7:43 PM","8:03 PM","8:23 PM","8:43 PM","9:03 PM","9:23 PM","9:43 PM","10:03 PM","10:23 PM","10:43 PM","11:03 PM","11:23 PM","11:43 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 7",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }
      ]
    }
    
function createList(className, station) {
  var newNode = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  parentDiv.className = className;
  
  station.forEach(function(stop){
    parentDiv.append(createStop(stop.station, stop.times));
  });
  
  newNode.append(parentDiv);
  return newNode;
}

function createStop(stop, times){
  var newNode = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var header = document.createElement("h2");
  var timesLabel = document.createElement("h3");
  var uList = document.createElement("ul");

  header.textContent = stop;
  timesLabel.textContent = "Times";

  times.forEach(function(time) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = time;
    uList.append(listItem);
  });
  
  newNode.append(header);
  newNode.append(timesLabel);
  newNode.append(uList);
  
  return newNode;
}

var container = $("#container");

Object.keys(routeSchedule).forEach(function(value) {
  var className = value.replace(/Saturday|Sunday|Weekday/g, "").toLowerCase()
  var newNode = createList(className, routeSchedule[value]);
  
  container.append(newNode);
});
```

```css
.southbound {
  background: green;
}
.northbound {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Route Schedules</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without JQuery:

```js
var routeSchedule = {

      "northBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station" : "stop 1",
          "times": ["7:16 AM","7:36 AM","7:56 AM","8:16 AM","8:36 AM","8:56 AM","9:16 AM","9:36 AM","9:56 AM","10:16 AM","10:36 AM","10:56 AM","11:16 AM","11:36 AM","11:56 AM","12:16 PM","12:36 PM","12:56 PM","1:16 PM","1:36 PM","1:56 PM","2:16 PM","2:36 PM","2:56 PM","3:16 PM","3:36 PM","3:56 PM","4:16 PM","4:36 PM","4:56 PM","5:16 PM","5:36 PM","5:56 PM","6:16 PM","6:36 PM","6:56 PM","7:16 PM","7:36 PM","7:56 PM","8:16 PM","8:36 PM","8:56 PM","9:16 PM","9:36 PM","9:56 PM","10:16 PM","10:36 PM","10:56 PM","11:16 PM","11:36 PM","11:56 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 2",
          "times": ["7:02 AM","7:22 AM","7:42 AM","8:02 AM","8:22 AM","8:42 AM","9:02 AM","9:22 AM","9:42 AM","10:02 AM","10:22 AM","10:42 AM","11:02 AM","11:22 AM","11:42 AM","12:02 PM","12:22 PM","12:42 PM","1:02 PM","1:22 PM","1:42 PM","2:02 PM","2:22 PM","2:42 PM","3:02 PM","3:22 PM","3:42 PM","4:02 PM","4:22 PM","4:42 PM","5:02 PM","5:22 PM","5:42 PM","6:02 PM","6:22 PM","6:42 PM","7:02 PM","7:22 PM","7:42 PM","8:02 PM","8:22 PM","8:42 PM","9:02 PM","9:22 PM","9:42 PM","10:02 PM","10:22 PM","10:42 PM","11:02 PM","11:22 PM","11:42 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 3",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }

      ],

      "southBoundSaturday" : [
        {
          "station": "stop 4",
          "times": ["6:59 AM","7:19 AM","7:39 AM","7:59 AM","8:19 AM","8:39 AM","8:59 AM","9:19 AM","9:39 AM","9:59 AM","10:19 AM","10:39 AM","10:59 AM","11:19 AM","11:39 AM","11:59 AM","12:19 PM","12:39 PM","12:59 PM","1:19 PM","1:39 PM","1:59 PM","2:19 PM","2:39 PM","2:59 PM","3:19 PM","3:39 PM","3:59 PM","4:19 PM","4:39 PM","4:59 PM","5:19 PM","5:39 PM","5:59 PM","6:19 PM","6:39 PM","6:59 PM","7:19 PM","7:39 PM","7:59 PM","8:19 PM","8:39 PM","8:59 PM","9:19 PM","9:39 PM","9:59 PM","10:19 PM","10:39 PM","10:59 PM","11:19 PM","11:39 PM"]
          },
          {
          "station": "stop 5",
          "times": ["7:01 AM","7:21 AM","7:41 AM","8:01 AM","8:21 AM","8:41 AM","9:01 AM","9:21 AM","9:41 AM","10:01 AM","10:21 AM","10:41 AM","11:01 AM","11:21 AM","11:41 AM","12:01 PM","12:21 PM","12:41 PM","1:01 PM","1:21 PM","1:41 PM","2:01 PM","2:21 PM","2:41 PM","3:01 PM","3:21 PM","3:41 PM","4:01 PM","4:21 PM","4:41 PM","5:01 PM","5:21 PM","5:41 PM","6:01 PM","6:21 PM","6:41 PM","7:01 PM","7:21 PM","7:41 PM","8:01 PM","8:21 PM","8:41 PM","9:01 PM","9:21 PM","9:41 PM","10:01 PM","10:21 PM","10:41 PM","11:01 PM","11:21 PM","11:41 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 6",
          "times": ["7:03 AM","7:23 AM","7:43 AM","8:03 AM","8:23 AM","8:43 AM","9:03 AM","9:23 AM","9:43 AM","10:03 AM","10:23 AM","10:43 AM","11:03 AM","11:23 AM","11:43 AM","12:03 PM","12:23 PM","12:43 PM","1:03 PM","1:23 PM","1:43 PM","2:03 PM","2:23 PM","2:43 PM","3:03 PM","3:23 PM","3:43 PM","4:03 PM","4:23 PM","4:43 PM","5:03 PM","5:23 PM","5:43 PM","6:03 PM","6:23 PM","6:43 PM","7:03 PM","7:23 PM","7:43 PM","8:03 PM","8:23 PM","8:43 PM","9:03 PM","9:23 PM","9:43 PM","10:03 PM","10:23 PM","10:43 PM","11:03 PM","11:23 PM","11:43 PM"]

        },
        {
          "station": "stop 7",
          "times": ["7:04 AM","7:24 AM","7:44 AM","8:04 AM","8:24 AM","8:44 AM","9:04 AM","9:24 AM","9:44 AM","10:04 AM","10:24 AM","10:44 AM","11:04 AM","11:24 AM","11:44 AM","12:04 PM","12:24 PM","12:44 PM","1:04 PM","1:24 PM","1:44 PM","2:04 PM","2:24 PM","2:44 PM","3:04 PM","3:24 PM","3:44 PM","4:04 PM","4:24 PM","4:44 PM","5:04 PM","5:24 PM","5:44 PM","6:04 PM","6:24 PM","6:44 PM","7:04 PM","7:24 PM","7:44 PM","8:04 PM","8:24 PM","8:44 PM","9:04 PM","9:24 PM","9:44 PM","10:04 PM","10:24 PM","10:44 PM","11:04 PM","11:24 PM","11:44 PM"]

        }
      ]
    }

Object.entries(routeSchedule).forEach(([key, value]) => {
 let result = `
  <div class="${key}">
            ${value.map(stop => {
       return `
                    <h2>{${stop.station}}</h2>
                    <h3>Times</h3>
                    <ul>
                      ${stop.times.map(time => {
                            return `<li>${time}</li>`
                        }).join('')}
                    </ul>
   `
  }).join('')}
      </div>
 `

  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
})
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```